# How can I change the keyboard shortcuts for single line scrolling in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, scrolling

To scroll a single line in gnome-terminal you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> in Ubuntu.

In other distributions (e.g. Xubuntu) you only have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> for the same behaviour. I would like to change the shortcuts in Ubuntu to work the same, but so far I haven't found an option or config file to change.

The reason why I would like to change this are two-fold: First, I find it more convenient (not having shift and ctrl above each other on a Thinkpad). Second, it is more consistent to the shortcuts for scrolling an entire page ( <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Pgup</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Pgdown</kbd>).

Also, I remember reading the reason behind using ctrl-shift instead of just shift, but I cannot locate that discussion anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! *"the shortcuts in Ubuntu"* Do you mean you're looking for a single shortcut key to do single-line scrolling in *all* applications or just in the Ubuntu terminal application?

Comment: I just meant the gnome-terminal in the Ubuntu distribution as opposed to how the gnome-terminal is set up in other distributions (even very similar ones like Xubuntu).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/3.8/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en, **there are some shortcuts that cannot be edited in gnome-terminal**. These are exactly: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>:

> [image: other keyboard shortcuts for gnome-terminal]

In Xubuntu you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> because Xubuntu uses [**xfce4-terminal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28Xfce%29) which is different by [**gnome-terminal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome-terminal). The same happens with other distros.