# Ubuntu 15.10 slow stepper scrolling in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, 15.10, gtk3, scrolling

Upgrade to 15.10, the stepper scrolling in GNOME Terminal is unresponsive, requiring between 4 and 7 clicks to scroll one line.

I use a theme with scrollbar steppers (the arrows either end of the scrollbar), when I open Terminal, and display a large file (e.g. /var/log/syslog) a single click on the up stepper isn't sufficient to scroll up by one line (as I'd expect). It requires between 4 and 7 clicks.

A "click and hold", scrolls the text very slowly (I guess, due to the number of repeated clicks needed for each line).

I suspect this is due to Gtk3 now 'smooth-scrolling' by default.

Does anyone know how to disable this, or adjust the 'step increment' so it's sensible (i.e. the same as the height of a line of text)?

I've looked around in the Gtk3 documentation:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrolledWindow.html

but there's nothing to indicate what sets the 'step increment' which I think is what's wrong.

Ubuntu 15.10 uses version 3.16.7.

apt-cache policy libgtk-3-0
libgtk-3-0:
  Installed: 3.16.7-0ubuntu3

Comment: How do the keyboard suggestions given in http://askubuntu.com/questions/247539/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcuts-for-single-line-scrolling-in-the-termina?rq=1 work for you? (I know you want to use the mouse but ...)

Comment: Thanks. They do work, but as you imply, I need to use mouse to get to the rough location, then switch to keyboard for responsive fine-adjustment.

Comment: The requirement in your comment is in addition to what you mentioned in your question? BTW, do you have legacy scrolling enabled, although I don't know if that applies to gnome terminal or "actual" gui windows: in your ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini do you have a line like this: `gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=false`?

Comment: Not an additional requirement. My main point is the problem with clicking the steppers.   And yes - I have warp-sliders=false, as I want to page up/down by clicking outside of the slider, as I'm familiar with.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how use of the steppers will get you "the rough location" to begin with?

Comment: My initial comment meant getting to the rough location using the mouse to page-up/down. In 15.04 I'd then use stepper clicks finely adjust location. In 15.10 I will now use ctrl-shift + cursor keys, until (hopefully) the stepper issue is resolved.

Comment: After dropping **overlay scrollbar** of Unity due to Gnome's `inconsistency policy` we lack  efficient scrolling feature with mouse. It's a pity.

Comment: To anyone interested, you need to **right-click** on the steppers for a decent speed, which is ridiculous, but currently works (tested on Ubuntu 17.10, change was introduced back in libgtk 3.18.2) CC @kenn

Comment: Thanks!  Good tip.  If only "single click" would equal "scroll one line" :/

Comment: Has not changed even with Noble. How to swap right-click with left-click to get decent scroll speed on the arrows? (gtk2 was better than this).